# Passing struct to unmanaged DLL with PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, .net, opencv, struct

due to several restrictions related to the project and not this problem in particular, I'm trying to pass through PInvoke a struct containing the data relevant to the Mat constructor of a Bitmap on C#.
In C# I receive a Bitmap, called frame, and in order to access the pixel data I'm doing:

```
BitmapData data = frame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,frame.Width,frame.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, frame.PixelFormat);
```

using `data.Scan0` as the `IntPtr` I create the struct for my unmanaged dll. Obviously, after calling my external function, I call `frame.UnlockBits(data);`

Here is the code
**C# Invoke**

```
[DllImport("ImageProcessingExtern", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void drawLine(IntPtr objPtr, ref ExportBitmap bitmap);
```

**C# Struct declaration**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
public struct ExportBitmap
{
    public int height;
    public int width;
    public IntPtr data;
    public int step;
    public int channels;
}
```

**C++ function declaration**

```
CVAPI(void) drawLine(ObjectsFinder* objPtr, ExportBitmap* bitmap) {
    cv::Mat testmat(cv::Size(bitmap->width, bitmap->height), CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, bitmap->channels), bitmap->data, bitmap->step);
}
```

**C++ Struct**

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)
typedef struct ExportBitmap
{
    int height;
    int width;
    void* data;
    int step;
    int channels;
} ExportBitmap;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

So far my code seems to work as long as I don't create that mat. If I modify ANY parameter other than the data inside the IntPtr everything works fine. When using the Mat constructor line I get an error saying the DLL is not a valid Win32 application(error code 193 from kernel32 LoadLibrary())

I've been stuck for about two weeks searching for a solution to this and I'm still not sure what is going on, I can only think there is a problem with how I'm obtaining the editable bitmap data, but I'm not sure what the problem with it might be.

Comment: I don't know the details of the libraries you are loading, but have you verified that you are running in the same bitness? For example: Are you inadvertently trying to load a 64bit dll from a 32bit application?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. Everything is built for 32bit.Do you need any additional data on the libs? The C++ struct and function are mine as well as that dll. Essentially the dll would be a wrapper for some very specific things I need done in OpenCV in C++ for performance reasons(which OpenCV wrappers like OpenCVSharp are lacking)